# Pip packages on NAO Robot

Tags: python, pip, nao-robot

I would like to install MQTT packages on my NAO robot but when I try to install them using SSH it does not work stating:

pip command not found

Then I try to install pip, also an error stating pip command not found.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Would you please share the exact commands you typed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py) to install it on NAO.
Then, you can use it to install some Python packages.
However, note that no building tool is available on the robot, so the pip packages that depend on compiled binaries cannot be installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download pip [version 18.0](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/81/52b68d0a4de760a2f1979b0931ba7889202f302072cc7a0d614211bc7579/pip-18.0.tar.gz) .
2. Then use Filezilla or any software that you are comfortable with and copy the file into the home/nao/ directory.
3. on Putty, I used root to install it. not sure if you should be in root or not. Type the commands below, one by one.

```
    tar -xzvf pip-18.0.tar.gz
    ls                #to see if the pip in extracted
    cd pip-18.0       
    python setup.py install
```

Then type `pip --version` to see whether it's installed currently or not.

It works for me on that way; however, you might face issue with openssl issue to install over SSH using pip.